# Visual Studio intellisense throws error with two dimensional .net collection. C++

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I wrote a program that creates a .net List of Lists.
The List I'm using specifically is of the `System::Collections::Generic::List` class in C++ managed code.
I then access the items inside of the inner list using the syntax `list[x][y]`. This compiles and runs just fine, and does what I expect it to. However, the Visual Studio 2019 intellisense throws the error E1767 every time I either get or set a member of an inner list.

While this isn't preventing development as the program works, I'm mainly wondering if this is indicative that there is something wrong in my approach that will come to bite me later.
If there's nothing concerning here, is there a way to get intellisense to ignore this use of syntax?

```
System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Object^>^>^ list= gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Object^>^>();
list->Add(gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Object^>());    //initialize array
list[0]->Add(gcnew System::Object());

list[0][0] = gcnew System::String("A System::String Object");        //E1767
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(list[0][0].toString());     //E1767
```

Comment: You can ignore it, the compiler gets it right.  A basic workaround is `auto temp = list[0];`, that temporary exists anyway.